# The Choquequirao route during the rainy season

Tags: hiking, peru, seasonal, machu-picchu

What are the risks of doing the Cachora to Choquerquirao to Machu Picchu hiking path during December?

I understand that January and February are the worst concerning rains.

My questions is whether the going in December is mostly about being confortable/dry or is it risky/forbidden/at great risk of cancellation.

Answer (score 3):

You've likely found that there are an abundance of articles on treking Machu Pichu, when where what how. One site that gives both a good overview, along with very detailed weather information is [Machu Pichu Trek](https://www.machupicchutrek.net) which states that is *not owned by any trekking or travel company, which allows us to provide independent and impartial information.*

Its summary of the [Best Time For The Choquequirao Trek](https://www.machupicchutrek.net/hike-to-machu-picchu/choquequirao-trek/)

> The Choquequirao trek is impacted by the same sub-tropical weather patterns that dominate throughout the region. Two main seasons prevail – a dry season that runs from late April through to early October and a wet season that starts mid October and runs through to mid / late April.
>
> The best time to do a Choquequirao trek to Machu Picchu is between May and September. Unlike the Inca Trail which is bustling during this time, the trail via Choquequirao is quiet and uncrowded. Do prepare for crowds in Machu Picchu as this time of year is the high tourist season.
>
> The main concern on the Choquequirao is the sun intensity, which is very high on many of the mountain slopes. Make sure to wear lots of sunscreen, have a good hat, and use long-sleeve shirts to protect your forearms from burning.
>
> The shoulder months to the dry season, April and October / November, can also be a great time to trek.
>
> The rainy months of December, January and February are not great for trekking.
>
> To read detailed historical Machu Picchu weather information for each month of the year check out our article: [Best time to trek to Machu Picchu](https://www.machupicchutrek.net/best-time-to-hike-machu-picchu/)

On the linked page, you'll see its summary, month by month (as well as charts of average monthly rain, drizzle, wind speeds):

> **December (Wet, Not Good for Trekking)**
>
> - **Overview:** Rainy season in full swing, too wet for enjoyable trekking but fine to visit Machu Picchu if you are taking a train from Cusco
> - **Temperature**: Daytime average highs are around 19 degree C (66F) and night time average lows around 7C (45F)
> - **Humidity:**  Average monthly relative humidity is 62%
> - **Rain:** It rains on average 20 days of the month and total average precipitation is around 110 mm (4 inches)
> - **Wind:** Average daily wind speed is around 6km/h (3 mph), with absolute maximum being recorded at 83km/h (51 mph)
> - **Fog:** Fog is possible